# Load texture at runtime and change texture import settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load textures at runtime from StreamingAssets folder and than changing their import settings.

Cant use resources because this will use for modding purposes

I wrote the following method but for some reason the texture importer always returns null.

```
private Texture2D LoadTexture(string filePath, bool normal)
{
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        byte[] imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        texture.LoadImage(imageData);

        TextureImporter textureImporter = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(filePath) as TextureImporter;

        if (normal)
            textureImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.NormalMap;
        else
            textureImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.Default;

        textureImporter.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;
        textureImporter.mipmapEnabled = true;
        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(filePath);

        return texture;
}
```

Comment: Is `AssetImporter.GetAtPath(filePath)` returning `null`, or is the instance returned not a `TextureImporter` so `as TextureImporter` is returning `null`? It would be useful for you to perform this debugging step.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I already did - the texture importer as Texture Importer is returning null this is what I wrote :)

Comment: You said "for some reason the texture importer always returns null" which sounds like the `textureImporter` variable is `null`, but that you've not diagnosed why. Since you're saying that `AssetImporter.GetAtPath(filePath)` is not returning `null`, but the result of `AssetImporter.GetAtPath(filePath) as TextureImporter` _is_ returning `null`, it's clear that `GetAtPath` is returning a type that's not assignable to `TextureImporter`. You need to find out what type it is returning. It sounds like it could be a `ModelImporter` or an `AudioImporter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AssetImporter` is an editor class so that you cannot use it in runtime. To load an image in runtime you just need to choose a suitable texture format and call `LoadImage` next. Usually a normal map uses a compressed format and is in linear color space.

```
private Texture2D LoadTexture(string filePath, bool normal)
{
    Texture2D texture;
    
    if(normal)
    {
        texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.DXT1, mipChain: true, linear: true);
    }
    else
    {
        texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    }

    byte[] imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    texture.LoadImage(imageData);
    return texture;
}
```

Of course, this is not certain, here is just an example. You may fill in these parameters based on your actual image. You'd better change the parameters to `format` and `linear` for better compatibility.

```
private Texture2D LoadTexture(string filePath, TextureFormat format, bool linear)
{
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, format, true, linear);
    byte[] imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    texture.LoadImage(imageData);
    return texture;
}
```